# Helly's theorem.

Tags: convex-analysis, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let F be a finite family of segments in R such that among any n of them there
are two intersecting. Prove that it is possible to divide F into n−1 families such that any two segments in one family are intersecting.

Comment: @CalvinLin Hey. Yup, I tried to approach it in this way that if I take some segments like for example 5 segments out of which 2 are intersecting. And taking an assumption if the smallest segment is contained in a bigger segment and has an intersection. So I can omit the smallest segment resulting in the n-1 segment that satisfies the theorem

Comment: @CalvinLin But it was all wrong as you can see as I considered segments in case families. Like I need to divide it into n-1 families. Now I got stuck here.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am pretty new to all this subject and somehow I am not able to visualise beyond. Even though I have understood different types of Helly's theorem but somehow I have actually failed to understand it. Since I am able to prove it.

Comment: I can't "see" because you didn't show any work (for several of your posts), so I (and others) have no idea what you're thinking of, or even what you know.

Comment: @CalvinLin actually I had previously written my approach when I asked the question but then edited it out since I got it what was wrong in this.

Comment: @CalvinLin And thanks for pointing out the other question. I had almost forgotten about it. I have attached images of what I have solved for the same. Please go through it and give any valuable feedback.

Comment: FWIW Showing a wrong approach (and marking it as such) can still be helpful at times, as it gives an indication of what you're thinking about.

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks I will keep that in mind from now on.

Comment: (I just realized that the 2 problems are not identical, so I deleted my original comment)

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, they are pretty much different.

Comment: With my restatement of the problem, it becomes [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2028438/intersection-segments?rq=1).

Comment: @CalvinLin thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, write out your working and thought process to demonstrate where you're at.)

Rephrase the statement to

> Let F be a finite family of segments in R such that among any $n$ of them there are two intersecting. Prove that there are $n-1$ values, such that each segment contains at least 1 of these values.

You can do a proof by induction on $n$.

The case of $n=2$ is Helly's theorem (or you can prove it directly by considering the left most right endpoint).

Suppose the statement is true for some $k$. Consider $k+1$.
Given any $m \geq k+1$ segments $R_i = [a_i, b_i]$ that satisfy the condition that any $k+1$ segments have 2 segments what intersect.
WLOG, let $R_1$ be the segment with the left-most right endpoint (IE $b_1 = \min(b_i)$)
Any set which intersects $R_1$ must contain $b_1$.
Consider any $k$ sets which do not intersect $R_1$. By the assumption applied on these $k$ sets along with $R_1$, there exists 2 which intersect. $R_1$ cannot be involved, so it's 2 of these $k$ sets. Apply the induction hypothesis, and there are $k-1$ points such that these sets contain at least 1 of these values.
Take the union of these $k-1$ points along with $b_1$, and we are done.